# Not properly grounded/earthed

Tags: grounding

I know next to nothing about electricity and wanted to ask for some advice. Apologies for any cross-posting.

I moved into a rented house in Spain a few months ago. Turned out it wasn't grounded. Providing a ground turned out to be a little complicated as the property is build on top of a few meters of concrete. The makeshift solution was having this house attached to the grounding rod next door (landlord's own house). However, I was still getting shocked (continued hot tingling upon contact sort of thing). The electrician investigated and said there was still 8V hanging round that wasn't being discharged through the rod, or something like that (perhaps insufficient capacity for two houses?) Anyway, he was adamant it was nothing, that I should shut up. The landlord wanted him to put in a separate grounding rod for this house anyway - and the electrician says he will - when he gets time - and this is, he said, a very low priority job.

Things can move slowly out here. It's been ten weeks and he's yet to have time. For a couple of reasons, the landlord is reluctant to change electrician, but if I should I can put on pressure, either for the original electrician to come out, or to find someone new who is bothered to do something. I do still get shocked when I come into contact with metal things plugged into the mains, but I've been promised that at this voltage (8V) it's not even worth saying ouch over. Also, I assume, it will not be doing any damage to the electrical appliances I currently have plugged in? So do I just wait? Or should I insist this is sorted ASAP?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Spain = manana... Get it sorted and quick - this is a fault and may get worse at any time... So, instead of "ouch" it will be zap and you're choosing accommodation with St Peter...

Comment: Get a multi-meter and check the voltage yourself. 8 volts should not be enough to notice, let alone hurt. Probe any two points where you've felt the electricity and record it and/or show it to your land lord.